# Replace an input file into image after selecting that image

Tags: html, css

i create a form where i upload image into database where i create icon input to select the image i want to convert that icon into that picture which i select after slecting the picture.

```
<label class="custom-file-upload">
                <input asp-for="imge1" name="imge1" type="file" />
                <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
```

CSS

```
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}

.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

little bit change  and add some javascrpt and jquery in it.

firslty add this

```
 <div class="form">
               
                <div class="grid">
                    <div class="form-element">
                        <input type="file" id="file-1" asp-for="imge1" name="imge1">
                        <label for="file-1" id="file-1-preview">
                           
                            <div>
                                <span>+</span>
                            </div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
```

then add this javascript and jquery

```
<script>
        function previewBeforeUpload(id){
  document.querySelector("#"+id).addEventListener("change",function(e){
    if(e.target.files.length == 0){
      return;
    }
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    document.querySelector("#"+id+"-preview div").innerText = file.name;
    document.querySelector("#"+id+"-preview img").src = url;
  });
}

previewBeforeUpload("file-1");
previewBeforeUpload("file-2");
previewBeforeUpload("file-3");
previewBeforeUpload("file-4");
previewBeforeUpload("file-5");
previewBeforeUpload("file-6");
previewBeforeUpload("file-7");
previewBeforeUpload("file-8");
previewBeforeUpload("file-9");
previewBeforeUpload("file-10");


    </script>
```

Also add this CSS

```
* {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            font-family: "Raleway",sans-serif;
            background: #f8f8f8;
        }

        .form {
            margin: 20px 0px 20px;
            padding: 0px 10px;
        }

            .form h2 {
                text-align: center;
                color: #acacac;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: 100;
            }

            .form .grid {
                margin-top: 5px;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-around;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                gap: 20px;
            }

                .form .grid .form-element {
                    width: 80px;
                    height: 80px;
                    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(100,100,100,0.1);
                }

                    .form .grid .form-element input {
                        display: none;
                    }

                    .form .grid .form-element img {
                        width: 80px;
                        height: 80px;
                        object-fit: cover;
                    }

                    .form .grid .form-element div {
                        position: relative;
                        height: 30px;
                        margin-top: -40px;
                        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                        text-align: center;
                        line-height: 40px;
                        font-size: 13px;
                        color: #f5f5f5;
                        font-weight: 600;
                    }

                        .form .grid .form-element div span {
                            font-size: 15px;
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **readAsDataURL** you can get file path and set to **img** tag.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {



    var readURL = function(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $('.input-img').attr('src', e.target.result);

            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }


    $("input[type='file']").on('change', function() {
        readURL(this);
    });


});
```

```css
.custom-input-file {
    position: relative;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.custom-input-file .input-file-wrapper {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.custom-input-file .input-file-wrapper .input-img {
    height: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;;
}


.custom-input-file .input-file-wrapper input[type=file] {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-wrapper">                           
      <div class="custom-input-file ">
           <div class="input-file-wrapper ">
               <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/proudcity/mebanenc/uploads/2021/03/placeholder-image.png " class="input-img">
               <input type="file" class="form-control ">
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i add this code it can not respond just an icon of image but not clickable

Comment: Also why you cannot wrap the jquery in script tag